# Parsing XML in JSFL?

Tags: javascript, xml, flash, jsfl

It seems that there is no xml parsing tool in available JSFL (Adobe Flash-extension Javascript script file) : http://osflash.org/pipermail/flashextensibility_osflash.org/2006-July/000014.html

So, is there an easy and cross-platform way to add a javascript xml parser?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I was looking for a solution to this problem as well (using Flash CS3). I needed to parse XML from a data file on disk. Combining the [suggestion of George Profenza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499138/parsing-xml-in-jsfl/3171986#3171986) I was able to get it to work with using `eval()`. The key is to remove the first line (the xml declaration):

```
xmlData = eval( FLfile.read( xmlFile ).split( '\n' ).slice( 1 ).join( '\n' ) );
```

... and you're good to go!

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer - been trying with no luck for ages!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use XML and E4X straight from JSFL using Flash CS3 or newer as the [Javascript engine got upgraded to 1.6](http://flashblog.robertpenner.com/2007/08/jsfl-updated-to-javascript-16-gains-e4x.html)

Here's a quick snippet that loops through elements in the current selection and traces xml:

```
var doc = fl.getDocumentDOM();//get the current document ref.
var selection = doc.selection;//get the selection
var layout = <layout />;//create the root node for our xml
var elementsNum = selection.length;//store this for counting*
for(var i = 0 ; i < elementsNum ; i++){
   layout.appendChild(<element />);//add an element node
   layout.element[i].@name = selection[i].name;//setup attributes
   layout.element[i].@x = selection[i].x;
   layout.element[i].@y = selection[i].y;
}
fl.trace(layout);
```

Comment: A condensed version of the above:`var s = fl.getDocumentDOM().selection;var xml = <selection />;
for(var i = 0 ; i < s.length; i++) xml.appendChild(<element name={s[i].name} x={s[i].x} y={s[i].y} />);
fl.trace(xml);`

Answer (score 2):

```
var xml = new XML(FLfile.read(file));
```

Then you can access all your nodes and attributes by writing this:

```
xml.nodeName
xml.nodeName.@attribute1
xml.nodeName.@attribute2
```

nodeName is the name of your node.
attribute1 should be the name of your attribute.

I hope this helps.

Comment: is this XML object somewhere documented?

Answer (score 1):

If JSFL uses ActionScript at some point, you can just do `XML(xml_string)` or `XMLList(multiple_xml_nodes_string)` as long as it's ActionScript 3.0 or higher. ActionScript 3.0 supports E4X witch is native XML in ECMAScript.

Comment: I'll try this once back to work but I don't think it will work as jsfl files are Javascript and not ActionScript files. Lot of similarities but differences too. I'll try anyway and report then.

Comment: @Klaim u can parse xml with e4x using jsfl ( http://robertpenner.com/flashblog/2007/08/jsfl-updated-to-javascript-16-gains-e4x.html )

Answer (score 0):

What works nicely for me is just creating a SwfWindow.  Working in JSFL is nice and fast because you can change out the file without having to restart Flash, but often ActionScript gives you more power.

My current project does a couple tricks:

1. I will create objects in JSFL and then convert them to XML.  I have to serialize them from Object format into a string which I pass to the SwfWindow (Panel).  From the Panel, I take the String can convert it into XML.  Then you can do anything you want in Actionscript 3.0.
2. If I just have XML manipulation, I will prompt the User for a XML files path in JSFL code, but hand the URL directly to the Panel, and have the Panel just load the XML directly.
3. Finally. For saving the XML, I will have to convert the XML to string via, 'xml.toXmlString()', but you also need to remove the '\n' so that you can hand the data to JSFL.  I will strip out the '\n' for '|' or whatever you like.  Then pass the string to JSFL, and you then can deserialize the string and change the '|' back to '\n' and save the file.  Either using the older 'Save Output Panel' method, or using the newer File Write method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I used to do that too, but I find it easier to use XML/E4X in JSFL just I would use in as3.0. xml.toXmlString() helps getting things back and forth without using Object

Comment: I've noticed that JSFL tends to be super slow, which I why I prefer using AS3 and a SwfWindow.  But to be honest, these's days I have been writing more tools in Air.

Answer (score -2):

```
function parseXML (xml) {
    try { // normal browsers
        return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml, "application/xml");
    }
    catch (e) { // IE
        var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = "false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
        return xmlDoc;
    }
}
```

You might want to read more on [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOMParser) and the [Microsoft.XMLDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx) ActiveX object.

Comment: Sorry but that's what I wanted to do before searching for another solution : DOMParser class don't exist in JSFL and I'm doing a cross-platform script so using ActiveX is not allowed.